# How to have my path and query parameters from my Post webservices be in UTF-8 encoding and display Chinese character correctly in the backend in Java

Tags: web-services, utf-8, character-encoding, urlencode, servlet-filters

I have this post webservice that takes in the query parameter that we make a string called newStationName:

```
@POST
@Path("/station/{stationid}/")
public void setStationOptions (@PathParam("stationid")Integer stationID,
        @QueryParam("stationname") String  newStationName,
        )
{
```

The problem with that query parameter is that if someone passes a name for the station in Chinese, it then it shows up on the framework end in latin-1 encoding or ISO8859-1 encoding and looks like a bunch of garbled text. The way I've gotten it to display correctly is by getting the strings bytes and changing it from latin-1 to utf-8 like this:

```
    try {
        decodedNewStationName = new String(newStationName.getBytes("ISO8859-1"), "utf-8");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        log.error("Can't decode newStationName");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I would like to find a global solution for this so that every time we receive a user inputted Chinese string from our web app on any webservice, we don't need to put this try catch block there as well.
I've tried playing with our tomcat and jersery server filters and encoding and that hasn't worked. I've also tried making the request and response encoding in utf-8 and that hasn't worked. I've also tried encoding the parameter of the url in utf-8, but that just sends the string back in url utf-8 that looks like this: "%C%A%D etc..." and then that needs to be decoded.

I haven't been able to find anything that has worked globally to this point but I feel that there has to be something I'm missing.

I have also edited the Connectors in the server.xml file to have their URI Encoding to UTF-8 as well as the server.xml file encoding itself in utf-8.

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8"  port="8080" 
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

I have also changed the encoding of the web.xml file to be in utf-8 as well, and the character encoding for the HttpServletRequest and Response are in utf-8

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to put non-Latin characters directly into the URL as query parameters? That violates the RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.4). The only characters allowed in the query are the ones defined in `pchar` (basically Latin and some symbols). You must percent-encode query data that is not in that range. If this is what you're saying, it sounds like a front-end bug. URLs are not UTF-8 encoded. Do I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to get my query parameters to come out on the framework side encoded in utf-8 and not latin1 so I can view Chinese characters correctly. I have tried configuring the server side. In the server.xml, I've made sure the encoding is utf-8 and have made both connectors I'm using have the 'URIEncoding=UTF-8' field. I've also changed the encoding of the web.xml file to utf-8, and the character encoding for the HttpServletRequest and Response character encodings are set to utf-8